# CScript Unicode flag doesn't work in a Python program in Windows 8

Tags: python, unicode, wsh

I have an application that uses Python 2.5 on Windows. It shells out to a WScript to get some data. The returned data could have content in many languages, so I need to support obtaining Unicode data.

Prior to Windows 8, this worked just fine. In Windows 8, however, asking for a Unicode response fails to return data to the Python program. The command-line version of the CScript call still works.

Here is a simplified Python script that shows the problem:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ["cscript","//NoLogo","//U","testscript.js"]
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=False, startupinfo=startupinfo)
(sout, serr) = proc.communicate()
print repr(sout)
```

Where `testscript.js` is a simple WScript file containing a single line (saved as a UCS-2 encoded file):

```
WScript.Echo("Test 日本語");
```

Running this on Windows XP, Windows Vista, or Windows 7 properly prints

```
'T\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00 \x00\xe5e,g\x9e\x8a\r\x00\n\x00'
```

Running this on Windows 8 prints '' (since the output is an empty string). If I remove the "//U" parameter from the call to CScript, I get 'Test ???\r\n', which isn't very useful for getting my unicode data.

Does anyone know how to get Unicode results from Python `subprocess.Popen` on Windows 8? I'm using Python 2.5 since that was the current version when this code was first written. I tried this with Python 2.7.3, and it has the same problem.

Comment: I've worked around this problem by opening a temporary file, sending subprocess stdout to that file, then reading the file.  It adds some overhead, but is acceptable for my current project.

Comment: Getting Unicode from Popen won't be possible as this uses the C standard library IO functions, and those always use the byte-based interfaces with the system code page instead of Unicode. But the new behaviour of `/U` not working in Win8 is intriguing...